# Is that anyway to check calculate API call time like browser inspect?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How to check network time on flutter using Android studio or visual studio code?

[image: view image]

Comment: You can find the answer in this question [Refer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735144/how-to-inspect-network-calls-in-flutter-application)

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin. Is it possible use without emulator? https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_stetho

Comment: You can try it with a device with cable