# How to inspect network calls in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making network calls in flutter by using HTTP package, i want to know  which type of response is getting for those calls

Comment: Do you try flutter dev tools, i guess - there is a way to monitoring everything about http request and response also (not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **flutter_stetho** dart package to inspect network calls

Visit https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stetho

Include this to your package's pubspec.yaml

dependencies:
  flutter_stetho:(version)  >> for example  **flutter_stetho: ^0.4.1**

**Note:** Based on dart version only, choose the Stetho package version

- For Flutter 1.7.x with Dart 2.4, use version 0.3.0
- For Flutter 1.8.x+ with Dart 2.5, use version 0.4.0 or higher

Comment: I like stetho, but as far I know it is for Android only and the development has stopped (at least for me unexpected)

Answer (score 12):

In Flutter 17.1 version, they given cool feature for inspecting the **Network calls**,

open developer tools by tapping on **open DevTools** icon (which is in debug console of android studio) as show in below image

[image]

After that it will the install the tools and open **Dart dev tools** in a browser as shown in below image

[image]

Click on the right side top corner flask icon(which is highlighted in the above image),
it will refresh the page automatically and display the Network option in the tool bar as show in below image

[image]

Now you can inspect your each and every call

Comment: This is not a good answer because as of now you cannot see request/response data in this tool sadly.

Comment: yes, i realised later this is only for recording the http calls with their status, you can flutter_stetho package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stetho) for checking the response, the only problem with this package is while giving release build we have to remove this dependency in pubspec yaml otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: I can't believe they're showing the headers in request and response but not the body. How complicated that can be? Why did they release half-done feature...

Comment: Well I can see the response body, but the request body is still missing

Comment: It only works in Android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use devtools network inspector:

1. Open command platte
2. Search for openDevToolsNetwork

Answer (score 1):

You can use [request_inspector](https://pub.dev/packages/requests_inspector) to see you request

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know what the reponse.body is I don't think that you need a separate library to inspect network calls in Flutter when you already have an powerful http library by the official Flutter Dev Team.

Sample Code:

```
http.get("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=stackoverflow").then((response){
  print("Status Code: ${response.statusCode}");//200 if successful
  print("Response Body: ${response.body}");

  // You can examine the response object either by referring the docs or using he suggestions you get in Android Studio / VS Code

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of me that returns a list of hotels from web service:

```
List<Hotel> list = list();
var res = await http.get('http://api-dadepardazan.nikoosoft.ir/api/cms/hotels',
        headers: {"Access-Token": "bt316x312ba44c6183aa81c2ce0d3eff", "Client-Id":"20629heeba32cc87fra6637b257d73"});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      try {

        var data = json.decode(res.body);
        var rest = data["result"];

        for (var model in rest) {
          list.add(Hotel.fromJson(model));
        }
        print('list loaded from web service');     

      } on FormatException catch (e) {
        print("That string didn't look like Json.");
      } on NoSuchMethodError catch (e) {
        print('That string was null!');
      }

    } else {
      print('Failed to call service');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use charles download [here](http://charlesproxy.com/)

Now add proxy in wifi connection in real device (No need to do for simulator or emulator).

Now do below code to configure setup with flutter `Dio` package.

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
      (HttpClient client) {
    client.findProxy = (uri) {
      return "PROXY <Your_PC_IP_Where_Charles_is_running>:8888";
    };
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to inspect network traffic from mobile apps is via a proxy. A superb tool for this is [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com).

Once you have Charles set up you don't actually need any additional Flutter plugins or packages to get it working, but you do need to set up Flutter to route through your local proxy (unfortunately Flutter ignores your device settings):

```
class MyProxyHttpOverride extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..findProxy = (uri) {
        return "PROXY localhost:8888;";
      }
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

// In your main.dart
HttpOverrides.global = MyProxyHttpOverride();
```

Of course, you'll need to change `localhost:8888` to whatever your proxy settings are.

I also wrote a more detailed write up about this solution [here](https://medium.com/hoursofoperation/use-charles-proxy-to-debug-network-requests-in-flutter-apps-2f2083275cad).